# Notification on getting an email from an user

Tags: notifications

I use Form 7 and Flamingo plugins to collect my users emails in Flamingo database.
So I wonder if it is possoble to be notified when an email is getting to my my database so I should not check this out every single minute.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Contact form 7 should send you email notification every time there is sumbisson. Check admin email under your contact form.